# Does this probability distribution function exists?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am getting a probability distribution of x like:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}\exp(-\frac{a+x^2}{2x})$ constant may change, but do we have any probability distribution that lies near to it, I even searched for Wikipedia list of distributions, but may be missing out somewhere?
When I plot on MATLAB I get a graph like(for a=10):
[image]

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is a lognormal, but it's not really that either. The point seems to be that it decays as $e^{-bx}$ as $x \to +\infty$ and $e^{-c/x}$ as $x \to 0^+$ ($b,c>0$), which does not seem like familiar behavior to me...

Comment: You have $-(x^2+a)/x=-((x+\sqrt{a})^2-2\sqrt{a}x)/x$ $=\sqrt{a}-(x+\sqrt{a})^2/x$ $=\sqrt{a}-(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a/x})^2$. So up to that factor of $1/\sqrt{x}$ in front, it is as if $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a/x}$ is Gaussian. Unfortunately this is also not an injective function of $x$, so even if you could ignore the $1/\sqrt{x}$ this would not fully resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a pdf, because, for example $a=10$:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%5Cpi+x%7D%7De%5E(-%5Cfrac%7B10%2Bx%5E2%7D%7B2x%7D))

The integral is not $1$, so it can't be pdf.

**EDIT:**
The only time it is equal to $1$, when $a=0.$ 
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}e^{-\frac{a+x^2}{2x}}=e^{-\sqrt{a}}. $$

So pdf then becomes:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}, x\in (0,\infty) $$ 
which is actually **Gamma distribution** with parameters $\Gamma(\alpha=\frac{1}{2}, \beta=\frac{1}{2})$. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ shape and rate parameters.
And in the end notice that this is exactly $\chi_{1}^2$ (Chi-square) distribution.

Comment: I think the OP intended to have an additional normalization constant. (Not sure why the $\sqrt{2 \pi}$ is there in that case, but still.)

Comment: As we can see then normalization constant must depend on $a$, and be $e^{\sqrt{a}}.$

Comment: @Mesmerized student Can it be a pdf if I divide it by $exp(-\sqrt(a))$. I have already mentioned that constants can be multiplied or divided(constant may change). I just want to know to which pdf distribution like this may correspond like $e(-x^2)$ corresponds to Gaussian, sort of like this answer I need. Making a=0 loses the whole point as it will make $x^2$ x

Comment: @Ankit Yes if you divide by $e^{-\sqrt{a}}$ then you have a pdf now. But I don't think it has any standard name. At best it might be a change of variable of some more standard distribution. An observation that might be useful: $(x^2+a)/2x=((x+\sqrt{a})^2-2\sqrt{a}x)/2x=(x+\sqrt{a})^2/2x-\sqrt{a}$.